# How to persist values across a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a time sorted pandas dataframe, where the columns are dates with boolean values as the rows as to whether a person was present at that date. If they are, I want to persist that 'present' to all the following columns (the columns are sorted chronologically).

I've reduced the problem to a simpler numpy problem. Say I have ndarray:

```
ndarr = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

**How do I make it so that if a one appears in one column, it's persisted to the right?**

My current solution iterates over the columns in python and I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant solution.

Current solution:

```
nd_store = np.ones(ndarr.shape[0])
for i in reversed(range(ndarr.shape[1])):
        tmp = np.copy(ndarr[:,i])
        ndarr[:,i] = nd_store
        nd_store = (tmp != nd_store) * 1.0

array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.logical_or.accumulate`.  `.accumulate()` basically makes any [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) work like `cumsum()` for addition or `cumproduct()` for multiplication.

```
nd_store = np.logical_or.accumulate(ndarr, axis = 1).astype(ndarr.dtype)
nd_store
Out[]: 
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: That's real nice! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the rows like so:

```
for r, c in zip(*np.where(ndarr==1)):
    ndarr[r,c:] = 1
```

Comment: Too slow. I have millions of rows. Probably should have mentioned that in the OP

Answer (score 1):

I would do this :

```
df[df==0]=np.NaN

df.ffill(axis=1).fillna(0.0)
```

Comment: posted the same answer as you :) deleted mine